# How to do function interpolation with Breeze library in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I would like to set up a function interpolation using scala. Does anyone know how to do this - preferably with [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) library for performance. An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have a gsoc project this summer to work on that, but it's not ready yet: https://github.com/chrismedrela/breeze/tree/linear-interpolation

What kind of interpolation do you want to do?

Comment: First or second order - I will keep an eye for updates from you. Good luck!